# Azure AD Domain Services Domain Controller's failing Replications Test

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-domain-services

I have up Azure AD DS, have joined some Windows 10 PC's, and created some security groups and GPO's. I am getting investigating an error in the Windows 10 System Event Log (Event 4, Security-Kerberos. The Kerberos client received a KRB_AP_ERR_Modified error from the server [AADDS-DC-SERVER-NAME$]. The target name used was ldap/FQDN-OF-SERVER/DOMAIN.COM@DOMAIN.COM. This indicates that the target server failed to decrypt the ticket provided by the client. This can occur when the target server principal name (SPN) is registered on an account other than the account the target service is using. Ensure that the target SPN is only registered on the account used by the server. This error can also happen if the target service account password is different than what is configured on the Kerberos Key Distribution Center for that target service. Ensure that the service on the server and the KDC are both configured to use the same password. If the server name is not fully qualified, and the target domain (DOMAIN.COM) is different from the client domain (DOMAIN.COM), check if there are identically named server accounts in these two domains, or use the fully-qualified name to identify the server.). I thought I'd do a quick test on the AADDS Domain Controllers with DCDIAG, and they are showing that Replications have been failing since yesterday. Results below:

Starting test: Replications [Replications Check,DC2] A recent replication attempt failed: From DC1 to DC2 Naming Context: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=com The replication generated an error (1256): The remote system is not available. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help. The failure occurred at 2020-01-17 10:48:28. The last success occurred at 2020-01-16 03:58:53. 34 failures have occurred since the last success. [Replications Check,DC2] A recent replication attempt failed: From DC1 to DC2 Naming Context: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=com The replication generated an error (1256): The remote system is not available. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help. The failure occurred at 2020-01-17 10:48:28. The last success occurred at 2020-01-16 03:58:53. 45 failures have occurred since the last success. [Replications Check,DC2] A recent replication attempt failed: From DC1 to DC2 Naming Context: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com The replication generated an error (-2146893022): The target principal name is incorrect. The failure occurred at 2020-01-17 10:48:28. The last success occurred at 2020-01-16 03:58:53. 31 failures have occurred since the last success. [Replications Check,DC2] A recent replication attempt failed: From DC1 to DC2 Naming Context: CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com The replication generated an error (-2146893022): The target principal name is incorrect. The failure occurred at 2020-01-17 10:48:28. The last success occurred at 2020-01-16 03:58:53. 33 failures have occurred since the last success. [Replications Check,DC2] A recent replication attempt failed: From DC1 to DC2 Naming Context: DC=domain,DC=com The replication generated an error (-2146893022): The target principal name is incorrect. The failure occurred at 2020-01-17 11:15:57. The last success occurred at 2020-01-16 04:54:52. 1777 failures have occurred since the last success. ......................... DC2 failed test Replications

Given that the AADDS DC's are supposed to be locked down, how is this happening?

Comment: So, I have been investigating further and if I run repadmin /showrepl, one of the DC's show no errors and the other continues to show: "failed, result -2146893022 (0x80090322):
            The target principal name is incorrect."

Comment: I believe that the cause may be "The destination domain controller receives a service ticket from a Kerberos Key Distribution Center (KDC) that has an old version of the password for the source domain controller." as per article https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2090913/active-directory-replication-error-2146893022-the-target-principal-nam.  How can I resolve this if I cannot stop or start a service on the VM's, or even reboot?  It appears I can only raise a support ticket on this if I purchase a Support Plan.  Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Raised a case with Azure Support, they confirmed this should not happen and raised with their backend team.  Issue appears to now be resolved.